# Is there an ANT task for watching a directory for changes?

Tags: ant, directory, listener, watch

It sounds a little far fetched to me, but is there an ANT task for watching a directory for changes and then running a particular ANT class when the directory changes?

Comment: Well I haven't found simple solution to this so I'm using a bash specific command for the time being: 'inoticoming --foreground ./src/ ant <target> \;'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If files can only be added to or changed in the watched directory, then you can use this simple [OutOfDate](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/outofdate.html) task from antcontrib.

```
<property name="watched-dir.flagfile"
  location="MUST be not in watched dir"/>
<outofdate>
  <sourcefiles>
    <fileset dir="watched-dir"/>
  </sourcefiles>
  <targetfiles>
    <pathelement location="${watched-dir.flagfile}"/>        
  </targetfiles>
  <sequential>

    <!--Tasks when something changes go here-->

    <touch file="${watched-dir.flagfile}"/>
  </sequential>
</outofdate>
```

If files can disappear from the watched-dir, then you have more complicated problem, that you can solve by creating shadow directory structure of the watched dir and checking if its consistent with the watched-dir.  This task is more complex, but I'll give you a script to create a shadow directory, as it is not straight forward:

```
<property name="TALK" value="true"/>
<property name="shadow-dir"
  location="MUST be not in watched dir"/>

<touch
  mkdirs="true"
  verbose="${TALK}"
>
  <fileset dir="watched-dir">
    <patterns/>
    <type type="file"/>
  </fileset>

  <!-- That's the tricky globmapper to make touch task work -->
  <globmapper from="*" to="${shadow-dir}/*"/>
</touch>

<!--
  Due to how touch task with mapped fileset is implemented, it 
  truncates file access times down to a milliseconds, so if you 
  would have used outofdate task on shadow dir it would always 
  show that something is out of date.

  Because of that, touching all files in ${shadow-dir} again fixes
  that chicken and egg problem.
-->
<touch verbose="${TALK}">
  <fileset dir="${shadow-dir}"/>
</touch>
```

With shadow directory created, I'll leave the task of checking directory consistency as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: It doesn't matter if the target directory has older files than the source directory.  I want an ant task that will watch the directory and when I save changes in the file in the editor, it will call a particular ant task.

Answer (score 4):

Yes there is an Ant Task that will do this:

https://github.com/chubbard/WatchTask

It requires 1.7+.  It can watch any number of filesets, and invoke any target depending on which fileset it came from.

Comment: Doesn't have a license...:(

Comment: @JethroLarson now it does. Added on the same day as your comment, it seems. :)

Comment: haven't figured out how to use it yet, don't know where to find the JAR their referencing, not enough documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to use the `Waitfor` task to achieve what you want.  It blocks until one or more conditions (such as the presence of a particular file) become true.

Comment: That ant task does polling though.  Isn't there a way to have the ant task subscribe to the directory for changes?

Comment: What do you mean with "subscribe"? Watch for file system events?

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the [apply](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/apply.html) task with a [fileset selector](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/selectors.html)

```
<apply executable="somecommand" parallel="false">
  <srcfile/>
  <fileset dir="${watch.dir}">
    <modified/>
  </fileset>
</apply>
```

The fileset will check the files against a stored MD5 checksum for changes. You'll need to put ANT into a loop in order to repeatedly run this check. this is easy to do in Unix:

```
while true
> do
> ant
> sleep 300
> done
```